# "The higher ... the lower"

Tags: english-to-german, comparison

How do I translate the following question:

> **The higher** he climbed up the mountain **the lower** he could see the village.

I made up this example just to ask you how to make such a construction like *the higher* ... *the lower* in German.

Comment: **To all close voters:** This is not a translation request and it should not be tagged as such. The sentence was given as an example for us to get an idea where the OP struggles. It clearly says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two more options:

> (1) **Je** höher er den Berg hi­n­auf­klet­terte, **umso** tiefer (*or:* weiter unten) konnte er das Dorf sehen.
>
> (2) **Je** höher er den Berg hi­n­auf­klet­terte, **je** tiefer konnte er das Dorf sehen.

(2) is antiquated except for short locutions like

> - je länger, je lieber
> - je schneller, je besser
> - [je oller, je doller](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/je_oller,_je_doller)

Answer (score 11):

> Je höher er den Berg hi­n­auf­klet­terte, desto tiefer konnte er das Dorf sehen.

It works the same way, but the first "the" becomes a "je", the second a ", desto".

Comment: Hi. I'm curious to find out why it is necessary to say "hoch" after using "höher"?

Comment: @Alone-zee first, I should have written it altogether, that was a mistake. Can't tell you exactly why, but I feel that "kletterte" alone wouldn't be sufficient to emphasize the direction. Probably the same reason why you would say: *The higher he climbed **up** the mountain*. But you are right, it also sounds redundant. "hi­n­auf­klet­terte" would be a better solution.

Comment: Oh, thanks. In the case of "die Ärmel **höher hoch**krempeln", on the other hand, do you think it necessary to use both "höher" and "hoch-"?

Comment: @Alone-zee "hochkrempeln" is a verb in itself. If you use "krempeln" alone, you will be using a different verb, which might have other meanings (depending on the region in this case). Just like "passen" and "aufpassen" are different words. But here again you have the issue of redundancy, which is only an aesthetic problem rather than a grammatical one. A possible solution could be: *die Ärmel etwas weiter hochkrempeln*.